# How to change keyboard layout switch shortcut in console

Tags: server, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, internationalization

I'm using Ubuntu 18.10 server. During installation I selected English as the system language and Russian as the main input one. It asked me to select the shortcut for toggling between the main and latin letters keyboards and I selected Alt+Shift.
How do I change that combination now?

Here is the output of `localectl`

```
   System Locale: LANG=en_EN.utf8
       VC Keymap: n/a
      X11 Layout: us,ru
       X11 Model: pc105
     X11 Options: grp:ctrl_alt_toggle
```

I've tried changing it with

```
localectl set-x11-keymap us,ru pc105 , grp:ctrl_shift_toggle
```

it did change the output of `localectl` respectively but the shortcut hasn't changed.

Note that I do not have any desktop environment installed and would like this done via console only.